# What does introduction rule for $\forall$ say?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $x, y, z$ denote (bound) variables and $a, b, c$ free variables or individual parameters. Gentzen’s rules are the following:

> $$      
> \begin{array}{ll} (\forall E) & \forall x\varphi \vdash \varphi[x/a] \\ (\exists I) & \varphi [x/a] \vdash \exists x\varphi \\ (\forall I) & \text{If }\Gamma \vdash \varphi [x/a] \text{, then }\Gamma \vdash \forall x\varphi \\ (\exists E) & \text{If }\Gamma \vdash \exists x\varphi\text{ and } \Delta, \varphi[x/a] \vdash \psi\text{, then }\Gamma, \Delta \vdash \psi \end{array}
> $$

> Here $\varphi [x/a]$ denotes the operation of substitution, that is, of replacing all free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$ with a parameter $a$. In case of ($\forall I$) and ($\exists E$) a parameter $a$ is required to be “fresh” in the sense of having no other occurrences in $\Gamma , \Delta, \varphi, \psi$. Such a fresh a is sometimes called an ‘eigenvariable’ or a ‘proper variable’.

It is from [here](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7).

What does $(\forall I)$ mean to say? It seems to me  counter-intuitive.

Is the requirement on $a$ that it must not occur in $\phi$,  neither bound nor free variables?

$(\exists I)$ and $(\forall I)$ are very similar, but why does  $(\forall I)$ achieve stronger than  $(\exists I)$?

Comment: The basic of idea of Universal Introduction is: If something is true for *any* object, then it is is true for *all* objects. We just have to make sure that the *any* is truly any arbitrary one: an object for which we know that it is part of the domain, but about which we assumed nothing else when we introduced it.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is the following. Suppose, from a set of formulas $\Gamma$, I've managed to conclude that object $a$ has property $\varphi$ - but $a$ itself was never referred to in $\Gamma$. Then $a$ can't be at all special in this respect: *every* object has to have property $\varphi$, assuming $\Gamma$. Basically, if I prove something about an individual without ever using any specific properties of that individual, the thing I've proved actually holds in general.

This is the rule underlying natural-language arguments of the form:

> "Let $c$ be an arbitrary [foo]. Then (argument involving set of assumptions $\Gamma$), So $c$ has the [bleen] property. Since $c$ was arbitrary, **everything** has the [bleen] property."

Of course when we introduce $c$, that symbol has to be "fresh." We can't say e.g. "let $2$ be an arbitrary number," since the symbol $2$ already means something.

Comment: Thank you! (∃I) and (∀I) are very similar, but why does  (∃I) achieve weaker than (∀I)? In  (∃I), why is $a$  not arbitrary?

Comment: @Mary $(\exists I)$ and $(\forall I)$ are two completely different types of rule. The rule $(\exists I)$ *gives us a sequent "for free,"* while the rule $(\forall I)$ gives us a sequent *assuming we've already gotten another sequent*. In Gentzen's system we're not really proving theorems, we're **deriving sequents**. (Both introduction rules give us sequents for free, and both elimination rules give us sequents contingent on already having other sequents.)

Comment: Even if we just pay attention to the conclusions of the sequents involved (which we **should not do**) there's still a balance here. While the conclusion of the sequent we get from $(\exists I)$ is weaker than the conclusion of the sequent we get from $(\forall I)$ (namely, "$\exists x\varphi$" and "$\forall x\varphi$" respectively), the $(\exists I)$ *rule* is easier to apply than the $(\forall I)$ rule. So it's a case of "less resources buys you less stuff."

Comment: Why this it so subtle? A problem that any treatment of quantifier introduction and elimination has to face is how to prohibit the following line of attack: "Suppose $\exists x \varphi$. Let $a$ be such that $\varphi(a)$ holds. Since $a$ was not mentioned in the hypothesis ($\exists x\varphi$), we've established $\varphi(a)$ for $a$ arbitrary and so we can conclude $\forall x\varphi$." This **will** be permitted if you're not careful setting up the quantifier rules for your system. It takes some care to "untangle" existential instantiation and universal generalization from each other correctly.