# Do these two $\forall$-introduction rules agree with each other?

Tags: logic

Enderton's An Mathematical Introduction to Logic says on p112:

> $\alpha \to \forall x \alpha$ if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

Why is the requirement of $x$ not free in $\alpha$?

Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic says on p69:

> 5.5 Exercises (b4)
>
> $ \frac{\Gamma \quad \vdash \quad \phi}{\Gamma \quad  \vdash \quad \forall x \phi}  $ if $x$ is not free in $\Gamma$.

Why does it require $x$ not free in $\Gamma$ not in $\phi$?

Do the two agree with each other?

Comment: 1st question: because $x=0 \to \forall x (x=0)$ is not true.

Comment: 2nd question: for the same reason. Apply the rule to $x=0$ as $\phi$ and $\phi$ as only element in $\Gamma$.

Comment: Do the two agree with each other?

Comment: The first one is not a rule: it is an axiom. For Enderton's "equivalent" result wrt Ebbinghaus' rule see Enderton, page 117: **GENERALIZATION THEOREM**.

Comment: 2nd question: if $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, and $x$ is not free in $\Gamma$, then is $x$ not free in $\phi$?

Comment: Because if $x$ is not free in $\phi$ we were unable to "generalize". The issue is: how to "generalize" without committing fallacies.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4077556/what-does-introduction-rule-for-forall-say) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993715/two-forms-of-generalization-rule-in-logic).

Comment: if Γ⊢ϕ, and x is not free in Γ, then is x not free in ϕ?

Comment: No. With a $\Gamma$ whatever we have $\Gamma \vdash x=x$

Comment: Are the two completely unrelated? In the first "α→∀xα if x does not occur free in α", if x is not free in $\alpha$, then adding ∀x to α doesn't matter, correct?